# LaTeX Error: File `lastpage.sty' not found

Tags: xetex, errors, templates

I'm using a [LaTeX template for a research article](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/stylish-article)

I've converted the `.tex` file to a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Results}

\end{document}
```

The file [SelfArx.cls can be downloaded here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/stylish-article)

When I compile the LaTeX code above, I get these errors:

[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You might need to update your TexLive-installation. You seem to be missing a package.
See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution

Comment: If you are on Arch Linux, you can `pacman -S texlive-latexextra` to get the package `lastpage.sty`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the package directly in your document. You may create a new auxiliary file called lastpage.sty and copy the entire code of the package that you can consult at http://www.biwako.shiga-u.ac.jp/sensei/kumazawa/tex/lastpage.sty.